# Django still stuck (Many to Many)

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

the idea is that students can send a ping to their teacher if they do not understand something, but first I am trying to get the student, teacher and whatever class they are in relationship
so in my models after a few attempts I have come up with this

**Models**

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 70)

class Lecture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Student,
        through = 'part_of_class',
        through_fields = ('lecture', 'student'),
    )
    lecturers = models.ManyToManyField(
        Teacher,
        through = 'Teacher_of_class',
        through_fields = ('lecture', 'teacher'),
    )

class Teacher_of_class(models.Model):
    lecture = models.ForeignKey(Lecture)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)

class part_of_class(models.Model):
    lecture = models.ForeignKey(Lecture)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
```

Question is adding a student field messes up, and Im not even sure this is the right way, it sounds right in my head but I am sure I am missing something, any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure that you need explicit intermediary relationships (Teacher_of_class and part_of_class). Instead, you should try utilizing fields within the other models to do what you want. For example, will a lecture generally have more than one teacher, or just one? You could model either of those with a field in Lecture.

Edit: Apologies, I misread your code initially with regards to the fields. My suggestion is to not use an additional relationship class unless you know why you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a lecture that can have multiple students and multiple lecturers, you do not need to have the intermediate models, Django will handle this for you if you don't specify any.  I would only use the intermediate tables if you wanted to store something with that relationship.

Also when trying to add your student and teacher objects to the lecture model, be sure to save them.

Your save code should look something like this:

```
aStudent = Student(name="Taco")
aTeacher = Teacher(name="Burrito")
aStudent.save()
aTeacher.save()
aLecture = Lecture(name="Cooking With Python!")
aLecture.members.add(aStudent)
aLecture.lecturers.add(aTeacher)
aLecture.save()
```

Hope this helps!